# What are the five grounds for asking questions?

Tags: sutta-reference

According to scripture, all those who ask questions of another do so from any one of five motivations. Which five?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On Asking Questions
Pañhapucchā Sutta  (AN 5:165)](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/AN/AN5_165.html)

> “One asks a question of another through stupidity & bewilderment. One
> asks a question of another through evil desires & overwhelmed with
> greed. One asks a question of another through contempt. One asks a
> question of another when desiring knowledge. Or one asks a question
> with this thought, ‘If, when asked, he answers correctly, well &
> good. If not, then I will answer correctly (for him).’